# Does Django 1.5 come with a default logout view?

Tags: python, django, authentication, logout

Django seems to come with a prebuilt login view implementation:

```
   url(r'^accounts/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),
```

which populates a template, by default located at registration/login.html.

Is there a symmetric implementation of logout? Can I write something like

```
   url(r'^accounts/logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout'),
```

and implement a template at registration/logout.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does - see the docs for the possible arguments it takes and the context it provides to the template:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.logout